# What hooks should you use to create a table only once?

Tags: wp-admin

add_action( 'admin_menu', string $createMySQLNewTable );

I saw this code inside the constructor and I think this hooks run every time we visit the admin panel, so it's going to throw an MySQL error every time we visit the admin panel after the table was created. What are all of the hooks that we can use to avoid this and only run it once? Also, shouldn't it be do_action instead of add_action?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_menu/

Comment: If it's a plugin, `register_activation_hook` - https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/activation-deactivation-hooks/

Comment: `do_action()` runs all the actions (functions) hooked to a particular action hook. `add_action()` is how you add an action to that hook. So, in this case, `add_action()` is the correct function to use.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins